# Write in specific row via FileWriter Java

Tags: java, csv, export-to-csv, filewriter

I have some data that I want to write.
Code:

```
private void saveStats(int early, int infected, int recovered, int deads, int notInfected, int vaccinated, int iteration){
    try
    {
        FileWriter txt = new FileWriter("statistic.csv");

        txt.write((String.valueOf(early)));
        txt.write(";");
        txt.write(String.valueOf(infected));
        txt.write(";");
        txt.write((String.valueOf(recovered)));
        txt.write(";");
        txt.write((String.valueOf(deads)));
        txt.write(";");
        txt.write((String.valueOf(notInfected)));
        txt.write(";");
        txt.write((String.valueOf(vaccinated)));
        txt.write("\n");
        txt.close();

    } catch (IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error!");
    }
}
```

I will use this function to save the iteration number and some additional data; for example:

### Iteration Infected Recovered Dead NotInfected Vaccinated

1 200 300 400 500

2 300 400 600 900

etc

A perfect solution would have the first row of the file hold names for each column, similar to what's written above.

Comment: Please add the text of your CSV file showing the rows and columns as you wish to add.

Comment: https://imgur.com/oxm4LQJ

Something like that. And the 3rd iteration will be in 4th row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this, it is a good idea to use an existing Java CSV library.  One possibility is [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).  "Google is your friend" if you want to find tutorials or other alternatives.

But if you wanted to "roll your own" code, there are various ways to do it.  The simplest way to change your code so that it records multiple rows in the CSV would be to change

```
  new FileWriter("statistic.csv");
```

to

```
  new FileWriter("statistic.csv", true);
```

That opens the file in "append" mode, and the new row will be added at the end of the file instead of replacing the existing row.

You should also use Java 7+ *try with resources* to manage the `FileWriter`.  That will make sure that the `FileWriter` is always properly closed.

If you want to get fancy with CSV headers, more efficient file handling, etc, you will need to write your own `CSVWriter` class.  But if you are doing that, you would be better off using a library someone has already designed, written and tested.  (See above!)

Comment: I downloaded Apache Commons CSV, but i didn't have time to do anything with that yesterday. That append-true is exacly what i needed! Thank you!